# Could = Would be able to? All the time?

Tags: modal-verbs

I was taught like,  one can switch "Could" with "Would Be Able To",
[in a sense of hypothetical usage](https://ell.stackexchange.com/questions/67535/request-contexts-for-could-would-be-able-to-in-incomplete-conditionals), and the future in a past tense like this one below.

> I thought you could catch it.
>
> I thought you would be able to catch it.

Q.1) But, can you put "Would Be Able To" into the place of the "Could" which is a past form of can?

> When I was young, I could touch a bug with bare hands.
>
> When I was young, I would be able to touch a bug with bare hands.

Q.2) How about the polite version of can?

> Could you do this for me?
>
> Would you be able to do this for me?

I'm not worrying about the subtle nuance differences. I'm just worried that they can't be exchanged at all.

Comment: More naturally, *When I was young, I **was** able to touch a bug with bare hands.* When in doubt, go for *simpler* tense forms - so choose *I thought you **could** catch it* over *I thought you **would have been able to** catch it.*

Answer (score 1):

For Question 1:

> When I was young, I could touch a bug with bare hands.

No, you can't use "would be able to" in this sense — 'would be' becomes 'was' here, if it was the simple past tense:

> When I was young, I was able to touch a bug with bare hands.

in the sense of: "I know that I could, because I did touch a bug with my bare hands". (Note: I'd add 'my bare hands' here personally).

If it's past AND hypothetical, then you could use "would have been able to" in place of "could have":

> When I was young, I would have been able to climb the Eifel Tower in 10 minutes

As in "I never tried, but I know that I was fit enough to do it". For Question 2:

> Would you be able to do this for me?

Yes, this is perfectly natural.

Answer (score 0):

The difference between Q1 and Q2 is that the former doesn't fit your *in a sense of hypothetical usage* requirement.

As it stands, at least the first part is a declaration of your ability. Rephrased, both parts become more hypothetical, and basically mean the same thing.

> When I was young, I could have touched a bug with bare hands.
>
> When I was young, I would have been able to touch a bug with bare hands.

Comment: Thx but I wasn't asking hypothetical usage for Q1 and Q2. Q1 was for Past-form of can and Q2 was for Polite could. I don't want Q1, Q2 to be changed into hypothetical nuance. I was just asking whether Could and Would Be Able To are switchable when Could means past ability or politeness.